# django pg:transfer from heroku to local database gets stuck on South migration history table

Tags: django, heroku, django-south

I am trying to work with the current version of the database on heroku locally. When I run pg:transfer from heroku's database to localhost the process gets stuck on:

```
pg_dump: dumping contents of table south_migrationhistory
```

It never actually fails, it just stops on that step.

Haven't worked in Django for a while so I'm not sure if I'm doing something obvious wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with `django_session`. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Seth, no I did not! I abandoned the attempt since it is a small project I just built a fake database for testing.

Comment: From little I could find online, it sounds like a file/disk problem on the database server. I couldn't fix it, either.

Comment: Very strange, I will try to give it another shot next week!